# How to join two tables using 3rd table in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle

I am running SQL query in Oracle DB where I am using schema names.

There are 3 tables (and the columns):

```
user (user_key, user_name)
roles (roles_key, role_name)
junction (roles_key, user_key)
```

Schema is: `internal_schema`

I can write a query as `select * from internal_schema.user;`

How can I join these tables so that I get `user_name` and `roles_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
SELECT fa_oim.usr.usr_display_name, fa_oim.usg.usg_display_name
  FROM fa_oim.usr INNER JOIN fa_oim.usg USING (usr_key)
                  INNER JOIN fa_oim.ugp USING (ugp_key)
```

Though, the schema name is not necessary if you run the query from the same schema.

Comment: Thank you so much, I get the desired results after modifying the column name as I made a mistake while submitting.

Comment: Yes, it runs correctly. I wanted to know how to add schema name in Oracle DB when using joins. I know it for MS SQL DB, wasn't sure about Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

A bit quick and dirty, but should solve the Problem. ;-)

```
SELECT a.usr_display_name, c.usg_display_name
  FROM usr a, usg b, ugp c
  WHERE b.usr_key = a.usr_key
    AND b.ugp_key = c.ugp_key
```

Comment: Oh, might be due to lack of Schema in front of table names: fa_oim ... forgot it in my quick and dirty approach

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for 3 table join

```
SELECT a.usr_display_name, c.usg_display_name
  FROM usr a INNER JOIN usg b ON a.usr_key = b.ugp_key
           INNER JOIN ugp c ON b.ugp_key = c.ugp_key;
```

But for your table definitions, you dont need to do 3 way join, rather a single join would suffice

```
SELECT a.usr_display_name, c.usg_display_name
  FROM usr a INNER JOIN usg c ON a.usr_key = c.ugp_key;
```

Comment: @Aish Please check if you really have these three tables. If you do have them, then check if you have access to them